# Spring MVC option not showing in Eclipse While Creating New Project (version - Kepler 4.3)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, frameworks, eclipse-kepler

I have try to create new spring MVC project. File -> New -> Spring Project After that i got this window :

[image: NewSpringProject]

but i didnot get the option Spring MVC project. The below error i got in my Error log section. My firewall is also off only.

---

**ERROR LOG:**
*eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0-ea
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Warning
Sun Dec 15 11:13:40 IST 2013
Connection to https://raw.github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-gemfire-sts-templates/master/builds/descriptor.xml failed on sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Retry attempt 0 started
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:154)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.doFlush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.flush(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.flush(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:715)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.performConnect(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.read(FileReader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.stream(RepositoryTransport.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.core.net.P2TransportService.stream(P2TransportService.java:139)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core.HttpUtil.stream(HttpUtil.java:165)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.content.core.ContentManager.readFromUrl(ContentManager.java:326)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.content.core.ContentManager.refresh(ContentManager.java:387)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.wizard.template.DownloadDescriptorJob.run(DownloadDescriptorJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more*

**MY Eclise Preferences Settings:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to a bug in sts if you are behind an NTLM proxy like me.

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3647

Answer (score 0):

1. From sts dashboard in Eclipse [choose the Install Extension option](http://pbrd.co/1jgvevy).
2. Check the Show Installed box on the top right side of the screen.
3. Check the Spring IDE box and install it.
4. Restart Eclipse and you are ready to go

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was to:

1. Switch to Spring perspective.
2. File -> New -> Spring Project
3. Now I see the 'Spring MVC Project option'.

Using Eclipse Luna with Spring IDE 3.6 plugin.